# ADGV C# DataGridView - find DataRow to update SQL

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview, sql-update

I'm trying to use auto-generated advancedDataGrid - ADGV ([adgv.codeplex.com](https://adgv.codeplex.com)).

My `advancedDataGridView1` contains "default" procedures to update-insert-delete SQL tables.

Update requires `DataRow` property from the `DataGrid`, which I'm looking for.

For example: it is filled with data (linked to SQL table) this way:

```
this.lTableAdapter.Fill(this.sQLDataSet.Lev);
```

Question: how to get `DataRow` property for the selected row or column?

```
int RowIndexNo = advancedDataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
int ColIndexNo = advancedDataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex;
this.lTableAdapter.Update(_TODO_DataRow_)
```

Comment: was hoping to do it with this DataRow DR = ((DataRowView)advancedDataGridView1.DataBoundItem).Row; but no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
int rowIdx = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
DataRowView drv = (DataRowView)advancedDataGridView1.Rows[rowIdx].DataBoundItem;
DataRow dr = drv.Row;
```

Comment: Works! Thank you.